# Windows 8.1 - Why are there multiple recovery partitions in the system?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1-upgrade, recovery-partition

```
DISKPART> list partition

Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    System             500 MB  1024 KB
Partition 2    OEM                 40 MB   501 MB
Partition 3    Reserved           128 MB   541 MB
Partition 4    Recovery           490 MB   669 MB
Partition 5    Primary            920 GB  1159 MB
Partition 6    Recovery           350 MB   921 GB
Partition 7    Recovery             9 GB   921 GB
```

Above is the list of partitions on my system that I recently upgraded to Windows 8.1.
Why are there multiple recovery partitions (4,6,7)? Shouldn't there be just one recovery partition? And what is the Reserved partition (#3) for?

Of the partitions 4,6 and 7 , only #4 shows any meaningful label:

```
Partition 4
Type    : de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
Hidden  : Yes
Required: Yes
Attrib  : 0X8000000000000001
Offset in Bytes: 701497344

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 4         WINRETOOLS   NTFS   Partition    490 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like every major windows OS upgrade creates a recovery partition. After upgrading my system to windows 10, I have yet another recovery partition.

It is relatively simple to figure out which recovery partition was created by the latest OS upgrade. Imagine the storage to be linear. The new recovery partition is created by shrinking C: from the right hand side. So if you open up the disk management console, the new recovery partition would be immediately to the right of C: volume.

Applying this to the question above, partition 6 is the current recovery partition. Partitions 4 and 7 are from the first Windows 8 factory install with partition 7 being the OEM recovery partition for the Windows 8 factory reset feature.

Source: http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/recovery-partition-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-4348.html